# How can I manipulate a 2D array in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

i tried to save list of equipments in arrays.
i need to add quantity for each equipemnt so i have to transform the one dimensional to two dimensional

how can i change this todeclare in state arrays as 2D?

```
this.state = {
        equipments: [{
            number: ''
        },{
            number: ''
        }]};
```

and how to setsate ?

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const orderData = {
        equipments: this.state.equipments.map(equipment => {
            return {equipemnt: equipment.number} 
        })    
    };
    createOrder(orderData);
}


validateEquipment = (equipmentNumber) => {
    if(equipmentNumber.length === 0) {
        return {
            validateStatus: 'error',
            errorMsg: 'Please enter a choice!'
        }
    } else if (equipmentNumber.length > 50) {
        return {
            validateStatus: 'error',
            errorMsg: `Choice is too long (Maximum 50 characters allowed)`
        }    
    } else {
        return {
            validateStatus: 'success',
            errorMsg: null
        }
    }
}

handleEquipmentChange(event, index) {
    const equipments = this.state.equipments.slice();
    const value = event.target.value;

    equipments[index] = {
        number: value,
        ...this.validateEquipment(value)
    }

    this.setState({
        equipments: equipments
    });
}
```

Comment: A 2D array is an array of arrays. Your state should be `equipments: [[// 1 array]],[// 2 array]]`

Comment: i used this syntax but it doesn't work in my case

Comment: What kind of 2d array you want to use? Can you add that structure too in your question

Comment: If each object in equipments represents equipment then I think quantity should be another key in each object. So your equipments array will be like [{ number; "", quantity:0}]

Comment: yes that's wha i need , i'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be easier if you use object instead of array

```
this.state = {
  equipments: {
    eq1: { qty: 0 },
    eq2: { qty: 0 }
  }
}
```

adding / updating new equipment would be as simple as:

```
addOrUpdateQty(id, qty) {
  this.setState({ equipments: {...this.state.equipments, [id]: { qty }} })
}
```

Comment: thank you, if i use this way i can't use foreach ti read all of them ? how can i do ?

Comment: you can use something like,
```
Object.values(this.state.equipments).map()
```